# Using both respondWith and waitUntil in a fetch event

Tags: javascript, service-worker, fetch-api

Is it ever necessary to use a `waitUntil` inside a `respondWith` (itself within a `fetch` event)?  Doesn't `respondWith` already `waitUntil` it receives a resolved promise?

Some discussion of this is [here](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1148#issuecomment-306535001), in which the following simple example is given in which both are used:

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(
    fetch(whatever).then(response => {
      event.waitUntil(addThisToTheCache(response));
      return response;
    })
  );
});
```

But couldn't this be written without a `waitUntil`?  As follows:

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(
    fetch(whatever).then(response => {
      return addThisToTheCache(response).then(() => {
        return response;
      });
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `return` statement inside `then()` ?

Comment: To return a promise (with the response) back up to `event.respondWith()`

Comment: You're returning a `value` instead of a `Promise` I'm not sure that's how it works

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then : "if the handler function returns a value, the promise returned by `then` gets resolved with the returned value as its value".  So in my example, as I understand it, `return response` is effectively the same as `return Promise.resolve(response)`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This will delay the browser processing & displaying the response by two seconds:

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(async function() {
    const response = await fetch(event.request);
    await processResponseForTwoSeconds(response);
    return response;
  }());
});
```

This won't:

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(async function () {
    const response = await fetch(event.request);
    event.waitUntil(processResponseForTwoSeconds(response));
    return response;
  }());
});
```

`waitUntil` tells the service worker to stay alive for ongoing tasks, but does not delay the response.

Comment: Ah good point, well made, as usual.  I like the way that you're exaggerating for effect, by using `processResponseForTwoSeconds()` instead of `addThisToTheCache()`.  :-)  In practice, a typical `addThisToTheCache()` function is unlikely to delay things for very long, so whilst using `waitUntil()` is optimal, I suppose that using `await` isn't that far behind (i.e. not a disaster)?  Anyway, I'll revisit my code to see where I should be optimising it further... steep learning curve.

Comment: I'd say it's usually likely to delay things. A browser can processing a response as a document as soon as headers have arrived. It can even begin rendering it before the whole document has fetched. By delaying that until the whole response has been cached, you're slowing things quite a bit.

Comment: @JaffaTheCake, re "*tells the service worker to stay alive*"; `waitUntil` seems like an anti-pattern. Why not let line 4 use `setTimeout` etc?

Comment: You can still use setTimeout, but you need to tell waitUntil about it (using a promise) so it knows which event is still being processed.